# Why can I not get user entity from another bundle? Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have some error:

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sector\ArticlesBundle\Entity\News::setAuthor() must be an instance of Sector\UserBundle\Entity\User, string given, called in /Users/roman/Development/Sites/Sector.dev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 377 and defined in /Users/roman/Development/Sites/Sector.dev/src/Sector/ArticlesBundle/Entity/News.php line 341
```

`News` entity:

```
/**
 * @var $newsCategory
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Sector\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 * })
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $author;

/**
* Set author
*
* @param Sector\UserBundle\Entity\User $author
*/
public function setAuthor(\Sector\UserBundle\Entity\User $author)
{
    $this->author = $author;
}
```

Destination `User` entity - `\Sector\UserBundle\Entity\User`

Destination current (`News`) entity - `\Sector\ArticlesBundle\Entity\News`

What is the problem here?

Comment: I believe the error message is self explanatory: `Argument 1 passed to Sector\ArticlesBundle\Entity\News::setAuthor() must be an instance of Sector\UserBundle\Entity\User, string given` you are not passing instanceof `User` to `setAuthor()` method. Most likely you are passing just a primary key...

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd Error message more than understandable, no issues. But why is not passed to the `User` in the `setAuthor`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that Doctrine can't load the related `User` entity, hence it does not recognise it as foreign key and just pass integer instead of entity. Try to remove leading `\` slash in the target entity definition:

```
/**
 * @var $newsCategory
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sector\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 * })
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $author;
```